# Set minimum bandwidth for Browser

Tags: firefox, bandwidth, steam

I want to download Games in the background while watching videos/streams on Firefox, but my video always stutters because Steam, EpicGames, etc take all the bandwidth. Can I set a minimum bandwidth for my browser so Steam etc only takes the rest? I know that I can limit the bandwidth Steam etc uses but my internet tends to fluctuate a lot so setting a hard barrier only helps when my internet is at top speed.

Comment: I don't know a "minimum bandwidth" is possible, but traffic prioritization definitely is. It sounds like what you're looking for is [QoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service), which is usually setup at the router level.  Many home routers don't support it, although most can be forced to support it using custom firmware like Tomato or DD-WRT.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is **QoS** or **Bandwidth Prioritization**, there are software that can also do it on the computer level. An example program is https://www.netlimiter.com/products/nl4

Comment: You likely need traffic shaping. There are ways to do it with some personal firewalls, but if you're using up all of your bandwidth you'll probably need to do it at your network firewall. Look to see if you have application aware priority in your router.